# Apply java script to ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have number of posts in a page as in facebook. I am using normal ajax loading on scroll to load every 10 posts. And each post has a comment box which is loaded with emoji.

Emoji script is loading fine at first but after auto load by ajax call the emoji script is not being applied to the loaded content.

textarea:

```
<textarea type="hidden" id="input-default '. $row['post_id'] . '" data-id="'. $row['post_id'] . '" class="input-default'.$row['post_id'].' form-control comment-text-box example4" placeholder="Comment..." style="width:100%;"></textarea>
```

using

```
$(".example4").emojioneArea({ useSprite: false });
```

More code

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function(e) {
  if (processing) return false;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.5) {
    processing = true;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/travelconnect_new",
      data: {
        first: fst
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $("#news_feed").remove();
        $(".comment-text-box").val('');
        $(".comment-text-box").attr("placeholder", "Comment...");
        fst = +fst + +10;
        $('#app').append(response);
        processing = false;
      }
    });
  });
}
});
```

Comment: $(document).on("scroll", function(e){if (processing)return false;
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.5){processing = true;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/travelconnect_new",
data: {first : fst},
success: function (response) {
$("#news_feed").remove();
$(".comment-text-box").val('');
$(".comment-text-box").attr("placeholder", "Comment...");
fst = +fst + +10;
    $('#app').append(response);
                    processing = false;
                }

            });
             });
        }
    });

Comment: Please edit the code I inserted for you. Do NOT post code in comments. When I formatted your code I saw too many end brackets

Answer (score 0):

Each time you load new content, you will need to run the `.emojioneArea({ useSprite: false })` command against the new content.

If you are using jQuery AJAX calls, you can place this in the same callback that puts them on the page, or use a Promise chain to make this the step after.

We could provide more detail if we could see what the request/DOM update loop looked like.

Comment: Basically .emojioneArea({ useSprite: false }) script disables textarea and appends div. If I load that everytime I load posts then the div is being appended multiple times to the pervious posts

Comment: Can you target only the new content when you load your new posts? You might be able to add a class to the existing comments when you update them. Something like: `$('.comment').not('.fixed').emojioneArea({ useSprite: false }).addClass('fixed');`